# COM Interop: What should I do to make a C# property usable as a VARIANT from VBA

Tags: c#, .net, vba, com, interop

Say I have a C# Nullable `DateTime?` property that needs to be consumed by VBA through COM.

```cs
    public DateTime? TestDate {
        get ; set;
    }
```

Unfortunately, Nullables are not visible through COM, so I would like to have the property return a something that will be seen as a Variant from VBA.

Unfortunately, I'm not sure how this should be written.

I tried using an `object` and a `dynamic` instead of `DateTime?`: while I can get the property value, I can't set it (I get *Run-Time error '424' Object required* errors from VBA).

*Note*: I don't have issues with making my library COM Visible: everything works fine and I'm able to use .Net types from VBA without problem, except for this particular issue.

Thanks for any pointers.

**EDIT**: I found an interesting page describing the [default marshalling for objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2x07fbw8%28v=VS.100%29.aspx#Y570), but I can't seem to explain why I can't set my property if it's declared as `object`.
I'm missing something.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here what I did to go around the issue.

#### Object properties

```cs
public object MyObject {
    get ; set;
}
```

When using a .Net `Object` property from VBA, reading the property is no problem and it will be correctly seen as a `Variant`.
Unfortunately, trying to set the property from VBA will fail.

However, using plain methods will work fine:

```cs
private object _MyObject;

public object GetMyObject() {
    return _MyObject;
}

public void SetMyObject(object value) {
    if (value == DbNull.Value)
        value = null;   
    _MyObject = value;
}
```

The check for `DBNull` is to get around the problem that VBA' `Null` is actually marshalled as `DBNull` to .Net.

#### DateTime?

Now, to make nullable `DateTime?` work, we can do something like:

```cs
private DateTime? _MyDate;

public object GetMyDate() {
    return _MyDate
}

public void SetMyDate(object value) {
    if (value == null || value == DbNull.Value)
        _MyDate = null;   
    else
        _MyDate = (DateTime?)value;
}
```

And in VBA, we can hide these get/set in properties (assuming we have an existing instance of our class in `myclassinstance`):

```vb
Public Property Get MyDate() As Variant
    MyDate = myclassinstance.GetMyDate()
End Property

Public Property Set MyDate(value as Variant)
    myclassinstance.SetMyDate value
End Property
```

#### A more generic way

This is a bit ugly since our C# class is exposing `MyDate` as GetMyDate/SetMyDate methods instead of properties.
To implement this in a more generic way so the mechanism is usable for all properties in our class, we can use a `Dictionary` as a backing store:

```cs
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
[ComVisible(true)]
public class MyClass {

    private Dictionary<string,object> backingStore = new Dictionary<string,object>();

    public object GetPropertyValue(string propertyName) {
        if (backingStore.ContainsKey(propertyName))
            return backingStore[propertyName];
        else
            return null
    }

    public void SetPropertyValue(string propertyName, object value) {
        if (value == DBNull.Value) value = null;
        if (backingStore.ContainsKey(propertyName))
            backingStore[propertyName] = value;
        else
            backingStore.Add(propertyName, value);
    }

    [ComVisible(false)]
    public DateTime? MyDate {
        get {
            return GetPropertyValue(@"MyDate") ?? default(DateTime?);
        }
        set {
            SetPropertyValue(@"MyDate", value);
        }            
    }
}
```

The `ComVisible(false)` attribute ensures that the properties are not visible from VBA.

And in VBA, we declare the properties:

```
Public Property Get MyDate() As Variant
    MyDate = myclassinstance.GetPropertyValue("MyDate")
End Property

Public Property Set MyDate(value as Variant)
    myclassinstance.SetPropertyValue "MyDate", value
End Property
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your own `NullableDateTime` class with the Nullable features such as `HasValue` and `Value` properties and `GetValueOrDefault` method.

Comment: But these wouldn't then be compatible with the standard Variants used in VBA and would have to be treated specially throughout the application, or would require yet-another-wrapper to make them behave as normal variants. I didn't mention it, but I actually have lots of these properties (they are settings).