# parser to convert .net dictionary or list to VBA's equivalent dictionary or collection

Tags: c#, vba, excel, vsto, c#-to-vb.net

i have to pass the .net dictionary or list type of object to VBA.
but when i am passing the .net dictionary at VBA side i am not able to see the elements of dictionary on .net side.

My code in C#

```
Dictionary<string,object> dict = new Dictionary<string,object>();
dict.Add("First", "1");
dict.Add("Second", "2");
dict.Add("third", "3");
dict.Add("Forth", "4");
```

i am calling the VBA macro from C# as

```
Application.Run("MyVBAMacro", dict);
```

in VBA side My Macro is

```
public Sub MyVBAMacro(var as variant)

end Sub
```

i also tried with

```
public Sub MyVBAMacro(var as Scripting.Dictionary)

end Sub
```

but didn't work for me.

in the WATCH window of VBA i am not getting the dictionary elements.

so i think .net and VBA objects are not same.
so is there any parsing class by which i can convert my .net objects to equivalent VBA objects?

problem is also with the .net List object.
.net array is working fine but i want to pass dictionary or collection type of objects to VBA.

please let me know if there is some solution to this.

Thanks,
Monil Gangar

Comment: Hi Monil, would [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30270904/converting-a-vb-net-dictionary-to-a-vba-dictionary/30312051#30312051) help?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use COM when doing interop between VBA and .NET
This is a simple start: [COM Interop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6453625/com-interop-what-should-i-do-to-make-a-c-sharp-property-usable-as-a-variant-fro)

But it can get a bit more intricate quite quickly, i'd recommend reading up on the topics of general COM, marshaling, reference counting and type libraries when undertaking such a task.

Simple example for making that dictionary COM Visible

```
[ComVisible(true)]
public interface IDictWrapper
{
    object GetByKey(string key);
}

[ComVisible(true)]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[ComDefaultInterface(typeof(IDictWrapper))]
public class DictWrapper: Dictionary<string,object>, IDictWrapper
{
    public object GetByKey(string key)
    {
        return base[key];
    }
}
```

Comment: Hii,
 i have already created comVisible interface and class as you have mentioned above.the thing is that when i am passing .net array data structure to VBA i am able to get that on VBA side.
but i am not able to get the .net dictionary type data structure on VBA side.
can u help me in this case.

Comment: Arrays get marshalled by default http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6cfh6e6(v=vs.71).aspx. There is a lot of stuff happening under the hood when you do that and it can become a bit dangerous to just use it as is.

Comment: so is there any parser to convert .net objects to COM or VBA type of objects? i am right now added a dll of Scripting.Dictionary on .net side and i am adding data to that VBA dictionary and passing that dictionary to VBA side and its working but it is taking hugh amount of time as my data is hugh for conversion of .net dictionary to VBA dictionary.

Comment: You will need to implement a COM accessible interface similar to what i posted. I can only repeat that trying wildly to pass types back and forth until it magically seems to work will lead to very bad things with COM. Take control unless you know exactly what you are doing.

Comment: ok but how can i convert my .net dictionary to that VBA dictionary.i am having a json structure in the form of string and i am deserializing that with the help of JavaScriptSerializer class. so it has created some nested object consists of dictionary and list.so now i want to pass this nested strucuture to VBA.so how i will achieve that?